# MPI_Bcast 'failed to attach to a bootstrap queue' when trying to BCast

Tags: c++, c, parallel-processing, mpi

I have written a c program to run on MPI with 4 nodes.

The program takes in an int of N elements. This is then Bcasted to the various nodes in MPI. This int is used to dynamically create arrays of N size on each of the nodes.

I have tried running this program and inputting from 64 to 1 million and this works fine.

When I try inputting 10 million or higher, MPI crashes and occasionally gives the following error:

```
Fatal error in MPI_Bcast: Other MPI error, error stack:
MPI_Bcast(buf=0x000000000067FD74, count=1, MPI_INT, root=0, MPI_COMM_WORLD) failed
failed to attach to a bootstrap queue - 6664:280
```

10 million is within the limits of an Integer, so Im not sure why this is occurring.

The code is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "mpi.h"
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int process_Rank, size_Of_Cluster;
    
    int number_of_elements;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size_Of_Cluster);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &process_Rank);

    if(process_Rank == 0){
        printf("Enter the number of elements:\n");
        fflush(stdout);
        scanf("%d", &number_of_elements);   
    }

    MPI_Bcast(&number_of_elements,1,MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    int *outputs = (int*)malloc(number_of_elements * sizeof(int));

    unsigned long long chunk_size = number_of_elements/ size_Of_Cluster;

    int my_input[chunk_size], my_output[chunk_size];

    for(int i = 0; i < number_of_elements; i++){
        outputs[i] = i+1;
    }

    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    clock_t begin = clock();

    MPI_Scatter(outputs, chunk_size, MPI_INT, &my_input, chunk_size, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    for(int i = 0; i <= chunk_size; i++){
        my_output[i] = my_input[i];
    }
    
    MPI_Gather(&my_output, chunk_size, MPI_INT, outputs, chunk_size, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    int iterate_terms[5] = {2,4,8,4,2};
    int starting_terms[5] = {1,3,7,3,1};
    int subtract_terms[5] = {1,2,4,0,0};
    int adding_terms[5] = {0,0,0,2,1};

    for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++){

        MPI_Scatter(outputs, chunk_size, MPI_INT, &my_input, chunk_size, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

        for(int i = starting_terms[j]; i <= chunk_size; i+= iterate_terms[j]){
            my_output[i+adding_terms[j]] += my_input[i-subtract_terms[j]];
        }
         
        MPI_Gather(&my_output, chunk_size, MPI_INT, outputs, chunk_size, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }

    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if(process_Rank == 0){
        for(int i = chunk_size-1; i < number_of_elements; i+=chunk_size){
            outputs[i+1] += outputs[i];
            outputs[i+2] += outputs[i];
            outputs[i+3] += outputs[i];
        }

        clock_t end = clock();

        double time_spent = (double)(end-begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

        for(int i = 0; i < number_of_elements; i++){
            printf("%d \n", outputs[i]);
            fflush(stdout);
        }

        printf("took %f", time_spent);
        fflush(stdout);
    } else {
        clock_t end = clock();
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: All buffer argument have to be `something*` but you're using `&my_input` which is `int**`. Remove the ampersand.

Comment: I have tried this and get this error: mpi_test.c:37:12: warning: passing argument 1 of 'MPI_Bcast' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   37 |  MPI_Bcast(number_of_rounded_elements, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

Comment: I don't see `my_input` in that line. That's the one I told you to fix. Make sure that every buffer has exactly one star: needs to be `int*`, not `int` or `int**`.

Comment: `my_input` is declared as `int my_input[chunk_size]`, so passing `my_input` or `&my_input` is the same thing. That being said, this is error prone since you might later want to refactor the code and declare it at `int *my_input`, so I recommend you pass `my_input`. you do allocate a lot in the stack, so you can start bumping the stack size (via `ulimit -s`) or replace the `int x[...]` with `int *x = malloc(...)` and see if if helps.